# Group By data from a text column

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I have a table in a database that stores invoice data. I am looking to easily view daily statistics on when a certain action occures. When the action gets performed a note gets added to a column called "notes" in that table in this format: "ORDER FILLED -G J- Apr 20 2013". "G J" is the initials of the person who performed the action that I am looking to track.  There can be other notes before and after that note. Unfortuntately this action is only logged in this one place in the DB and I do not have control over how the data is logged. I am looking to create a daily report of how many times each user performed this action yesterday. The query below works perfectly however it returns the results of each user as a seperate result and I'd liek them to be all in one grid. I am not a programmer or SQL expert, I am just tryning to scratch something together that will work. Is there an easy way to modify my query below so that I can have one table with two columns... Column 1 should be "User" and column 2 should be "Orders Filled" I want to have a row for each employee, how many times they performed the action and lastly a row for total.

```
declare @date VARCHAR(12)


SET @date = (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE()-1, 100))


select count(invoice_id) as Employee1 from invoice 
where notes like '%ORDER FILLED -G J- '+@date+'%'

select count(invoice_id) as Employee2 from invoice 
where notes like '%ORDER FILLED -S L- '+@date+'%'

select count(invoice_id) as Employee3 from invoice 
where notes like '%ORDER FILLED -E S- '+@date+'%'

select count(invoice_id) as Employee4 from invoice 
where notes like '%ORDER FILLED -R A- '+@date+'%'

select count(invoice_id) as Total from invoice 
where notes like '%ORDER FILLED -% %- '+@date+'%'
```

Comment: If possible, you should redesign the table so that it's in [1NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form): the filled date and filling person should be in their own columns.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I do not have the ability to redesign the table or modify in any way. I am attempting to create a report on 3rd party DB that I do not have control over. (I am allowed to read it though, just not modify the way it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this might work

```
select substring(notes, 13, 4) filledby -- should be -G J- if I counted right
, count(*) records
from invoice
where notes like '% ' + @date + '%'
group by substring(notes, 13, 4)
```

Note that different RDBMSs have different syntaxes for substrings, and you didn't specify yours.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, that almost seems to work, but the problem that I am seeing is that sometimes there are other notes in front of this string of text in that column, thats why I was using the % in front of the note. So counting 13 characters in from the start does not work, is there a way to count 13 characters in from where "%ORDER FILLED" starts?   MS SQL 2012 is the DB by the way

Comment: Figured it out.... just added (PATINDEX('%ORDER FILLED%', notes))+13 and that does the trick! Thanks for the help